# How to change the extension of a file?

Tags: c++, file-io, notepad

I am currently working on project where I need to add some message at the end of a file and then I want to change its extension.

I know how to add the message at the end of the file; my code:

```
_ofstream myfile;
_myfile.open("check.txt", std::ios_base::app);
_myfile << "Thanks for your help.\n";
```

How can I change the file's extension?

Comment: Did you consider to read the [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) first?

Comment: Sorry, Currently I can not publish my code due to restrictions from my professor.

Comment: We don't want your entire code, we want to see what you tried to fix the problem (which is hopefully only a small part of your code). Appending text to a file is a very basic thing, and @πάνταῥεῖ already linked you the documentation. Also just asking for *"give me syntax of that"* is very frowned upon, SO is not a coding service.

Comment: **bold**ofstream myfile;
**bold**myfile.open("check.txt", std::ios_base::app);
**bold**myfile << "Thanks for your help.\n";

This is my code . But I need a solution for How to change extension of .txt file to any other format using c++?

Comment: @Dhruval You can [edit] your post if you want to improve it. I did it for you; you can edit your post further if you want to add of change something. Also, you got an answer (see below).

Comment: Sorry I am New user .I don't know how to differ my code from my text.Please Help.@anatolyg and thank You

Answer (score 1):

Actualy, it is very simple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>


using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    ofstream fout("test.txt", ios_base::app);
    fout << "My cool string";
    fout.close();
    rename("test.txt", "test.txt1");

    return 0;
}
```